# img not found error on ipad but not on chrome or firefox

Tags: ipad, magento, caching, cross-browser, cross-platform

Our Magento site was working fine on desktop, ipad etc but recently we are getting a image error on iPads when we visit a product url

The error is:
**Image not found: http:/???/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/???/i/m/img_0111.gif**

I've checked the caching folder on the cPanel & the image is their & we don't get this error on desktops or android phones.

Everything was working before but we added some new products & this started happening on the old & new products alike.  I've made some small css changes lately regarding img sizes but I changed them all back & the error still occurred.

I have no idea what could be causing this so would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be simple cause to this problem, the images uploaded to the site where GIFs over 1mb & the iPad could  not download them for some reason, maybe they were too large or took too long to download.

Anyway it works fine now that we are uploading JPEGs under 200kb.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like permission error.Check your media folder for permitions. My suggestion try it with 777 to all folders and subfolders.If it works then you know it is permission problem.After you are sure change it to 755 again for all folders AND subfolders.If it breaks again you have to change the ownership of the folder. 
Hope that make sense!

Comment: thanks vbak, i tried this but it didn't work.  The parent folders of the image were already set to 777 & while the image was set to 666 when I changed it to 777, it made no difference.

Comment: May i ask how did you add the products?Programmatically or through backend?

Comment: Try that too..

Go to `admin > System > Configuration > Catalog`

and upload some Image Place Holders…